# use of DefaultComboBoxModel for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

What is the meaning of DefaultComboBoxModel? Why is it use while using JComboBox? In Eclipse it shows `DefaultComboBoxModel is a raw type. References to generic type DefaultComboBoxModel<E> should be parameterized`.

I can't understand what does it mean.
I tried to search in internet but can not find required answer for my question. Please can anyone clarify me the use of DefaultComboBoxModel?

```
final DefaultComboBoxModel progName = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

      progName.addElement("JAVA");
      progName.addElement("PHP");
      progName.addElement("ASP");
      progName.addElement("PYTHON");

      final JComboBox langCombo = new JComboBox(progName);    
      langCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with [How to use combo boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Model-View-Controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) and [Java Generics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 1):

```
final DefaultComboBoxModel<String> progName = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
...
final JComboBox<String> langCombo = new JComboBox<String>(progName);
```

You need to tell the model and combo box the type of data being added to the model so compiler time checking can be done.

Read up on [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) for more information.

Comment: You "need" to, but it doesn't hurt as it will add compile time protection ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, agreed, but the OP is questioning the Eclipse message. I don't use an IDE but I would guess you need to do this  to get rid of the message.

Comment: Don't Eclipse either, could be an IDE warning/suggestion - nb: Just a general nitpick, otherwise fine ;)